# DI a class which inherits from EventArgs?

Tags: c#, events, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, moq

Im trying to DI a class which inherits EventArgs. When i DI this class into a separate class i have, i keep getting an error saying it "there is no implicit reference conversion."

Below is the declaration of the VerificationStatusEventArgs class.

```
namespace Jimbob.CsvImporter.DataVerification
{
    public interface IVerificationStatusEventArgs
    {
        string SummaryMessage { get; set; }

        bool CarriedOutToCompletion { get; set; }

        List<String> ErrorLog { get; set; }
    }

    public class VerificationStatusEventArgs:EventArgs, IVerificationStatusEventArgs
    {
        public string SummaryMessage { get; set; }

        public bool CarriedOutToCompletion { get; set; }

        public List<String> ErrorLog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i have tried to inject this into the following class thus but cant declare the events using the interface.

```
public interface ICsvFileVerification
{
//Error here (1)
    event EventHandler<IVerificationStatusEventArgs> VerificationCompleted;

    event EventHandler UpdateProgressBar;

    //..
}

public class CsvFileVerification : ICsvFileVerification
{
    IUserInputEntity _entity;
    IEntityVerification _entityVerification;
    IVerificationStatusEventArgs _dataVerificationStatus;


    public CsvFileVerification(IEntityVerification entityVerification, IVerificationStatusEventArgs dataVerificationStatus)
    {
        _entityVerification = entityVerification;
        _dataVerificationStatus = dataVerificationStatus;
    }
//Error here (2)
    public event EventHandler<IVerificationStatusEventArgs> VerificationCompleted;
    public event EventHandler UpdateProgressBar;

    public void VerifyDataManagerAsync()
    {
        _dataVerificationStatus.CarriedOutToCompletion = true;
        _dataVerificationStatus.ErrorLog = new List<string>();

        if (!_cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                _entityVerification.VerifyUserInputManager(_entity, _dataVerificationStatus.ErrorLog);
                if (_dataVerificationStatus.ErrorLog.Count > 0)
                {
                    _dataVerificationStatus.CarriedOutToCompletion = false;
                    _dataVerificationStatus.SummaryMessage = "Verification of user inputs failed.";
                    return;
                }

                VerifyDataTypes();
            }

            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                //...
            }

            finally
            {
                //Call method to raise event.
                OnVerificationStatusEventArgs(this, _dataVerificationStatus);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _dataVerificationStatus.SummaryMessage = "Operation was canceled before the task could be started." + Environment.NewLine;
            _dataVerificationStatus.CarriedOutToCompletion = false;
            OnVerificationStatusEventArgs(this, _dataVerificationStatus);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Raises an event on the GUI thread which should be used to notify the user that the task is
    /// completed and, if relevant, the exception message that was thrown.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected virtual void OnVerificationStatusEventArgs(object sender, IVerificationStatusEventArgs e)
    {
//Error here (3)
        EventHandler<IVerificationStatusEventArgs> TempHandler = VerificationCompleted;

        //Avoid possible race condition.
        if (TempHandler != null)
        {
            TempHandler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

Errors:
(1), (2) & (3):

```
The type 'Jimbob.CsvImporter.DataVerification.IVerificationStatusEventArgs' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'. 

There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Jimbob.CsvImporter.DataVerification.IVerificationStatusEventArgs' to 'System.EventArgs'.
```

The main purpose was so i could test VerifyDataManagerAsync(). I guess this could actually be done with just an instance of the VerificationStatusEventArgs class.

Someone in c# chat suggested that this wasnt possible in .net 4.0? Is this the case or is there a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I'm trying to DI a class" - nor what you're really trying to do. It should be absolutely possible to construct an instance of this as normal in tests... but if you could clarify *exactly* what you're trying to do and the problem you're having, that would help a lot.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry for the original question. I have added the 2nd class, hopefully that makes things a little more clearer.

Comment: That's now well over 100 lines of code. Any chance you could come up with a rather shorter example? You still haven't said *exactly* what the error is, or where you've got it.

Comment: What is the injection framework - MEF, Unity, RYO (reflection)???

Comment: I will trim it down and put comments in where the errors are, sorry.

Comment: IAbstract, im not using an injection framework

Answer (score 2):

Definition:

```
delegate System.EventArgs<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
```

means that whatever you place inside brackets must inherit from `EventArgs`.
`IVerificationStatusEventArgs` does not inherit `EventArgs`. You can change your inheritance chain by making abstract class that inherits from `EventArgs` and then inherit from it.

```
public abstract class VerificationStatusEventArgsBase : EventArgs
{
    //some abstract methods here
}

public class VerificationStatusEventArgs : VerificationStatusEventArgsBase 
{
    //implement your abstract methods
}
```

Then it should work.

P.S. You can read about constraints on generics [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970).

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I gave it a shot and its not working, As far as im aware i can only refer to a class via its interface type n not by its Abstract class it inherits. U might be onto something though so i will experiment with this approach tonight. +1 for ur help.

Comment: Ok. So you are not using an injection framework. So what are you using? What do you mean by "i can only refer to a class via its interface"?

Comment: Correct, im manually injecting at present since this is the first project ive done this with. (My above comment may be incorrect, if thats the case, im sorry) but as far as i was aware, an interface variable can refer to any object that implements that interface. I dont believe thats possible with abstract classes, so i couldnt mock it, inorder to unit test methods which use the class. I might be making this overly complicated since there isnt alot in the VerificationStatusEventArgs class, but still curious to see if it possible.

Comment: How do You "manually inject"? And there is nothing you can do with interface that can't be done with abstract class. Virtualization and referencing by base type is possible in any type of inheritance.

Comment: i guess i was mistaken, sorry.